# Proving for an AR(2) process that $E[X_t | F_{t-1}]=E[X_t | F_{t-2}]=E[X_t | F_{t-3}]$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, autoregressive, conditional-expectation

An exercise states:

Using the law of iterated expectations applied to an AR(2) process, verify that
$E_{t−k} . . . E_{t−1} (X_t ) = E(X_t |F_{t−k} ) $ for $  k = 1, 2, 3 $ where $ E_{t−k} (X_t ) = E(X_t |F_{t−k} ) .$

I dislike the way the question is posed and I think it can be reduced to proving:

$$E[X_t | F_{t-1}]=E[X_t | F_{t-2}]=E[X_t | F_{t-3}]$$

I proceeded in this way:

$$E[X_t|F_{t-1}] =E[ \phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t | F_{t-1}] = \phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} \tag{1}$$

by linearity of the expected value and because $E[ \epsilon_t] = 0 $ (white noise).

Then:

$$E[X_t|F_{t-2}] =E[ \phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t | F_{t-2}] = E[\phi_{1}X_{t-1}|F_{t-2}] + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} = \phi_{1}^2X_{t-2} + \phi_{2}\phi_1X_{t-3} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} $$

Now it seems that substituting the AR(2) again in $(1)$ we would get the required result (the equality between the two conditional expected values):

$$\phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} = \phi_{1}^2X_{t-2} + \phi_{2}\phi_1X_{t-3} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t-1}$$

except for that pesky $\epsilon_{t-1}$ .

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you think is an equivalent statement, it is not.
Think intuitively: if it was the case that $E[X_t | F_{t-1}]=E[X_t | F_{t-2}]=E[X_t | F_{t-3}]$ (it is not), it would mean that new information (as reflected in the fact that $F_{t-3} \subset  F_{t-2} \subset F_{t-1}$), would not change your "average anticipation" of what the value of $X_t$ might be (It would be as though the white noise was zero- does this raise a flag?)

Mathematically, you derived correctly

$$E[X_t\mid F_{t-1}] = \phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} \tag{1}$$

while we have

$$E[X_t|F_{t-2}] =E[ \phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t \mid F_{t-2}] = \phi_{1}E[ X_{t-1} \mid F_{t-2}]+ \phi_{2}X_{t-2} \tag{2}$$

For $(1)$ to be equal to $(2)$ we must have

$$X_{t-1} = ?\; E[ X_{t-1} \mid F_{t-2}]$$

Can we? (we could, if the white noise was zero...)

This tedious exercise asks you to verify that

$$E\Big(E\Big[E(\phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t\mid F_{t-1})\mid F_{t-2}\Big]\mid F_{t-3}\Big) = E\Big(\phi_{1}X_{t-1} + \phi_{2}X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t\mid F_{t-3}\Big)$$

so that I guess, you "see with your own eyes" that the law of iterated expectations holds (which is essentially part of the definition of the conditional expectation, see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations/95972#95972) if you are interested).

Start "getting rid" of expected values by using the functional form of the $X$'s when necessary, in order to express the future that is not covered by the immediately available sigma-algebra, with the present and the past that is.