# iterated expectation conditional on two variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, conditioning

How to prove that $E[Y]=E[E[E[Y|X_1, X_2]]]$ ?

PS. I don't see how $E[E(Y|X_{1},X_{2})|X_{1}]=Y[Y|X_{1}]$ and $E[Y]=E[E(Y|X_{1})]$ can be used here. But it feels close. Please help, I'm stuck
PPS. Thanks @Deep North. Let's consider the case when X1 is independent of X2

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations read here

Comment: I am also wondering if your question is missing some conditions.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations does not answer E[Y]=E[E[E[Y|X1,X2]]]

Comment: I am trying to understand Appendix A in http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=17999182 In principle, they may consider the case when X1 is independent of X2. But I reckon, it is not the case there, I am not sure

Comment: Ok, I read the appendix very quickly, I think the question is not about law of iterated expectations. I think the key to understand Appendix A is that $E(Y|x_1,x_2)$ is a function of $x_1,x_2$

Comment: ...E(Y|x) is a function of x... That's clear. But still I don't get  the very first line in the very first formula in the Appendix A

Comment: The notation is ambiguous.  By definition, $E[Y|X_1,X_2]$ is a function of $(X_1,X_2)$. But exactly what distributions correspond to the outer two expectations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E[Y \mid X_1, X_2]$ is a *random variable* that is a *function* 
$g(X_1, X_2)$ of the
random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. How do we find the expected value
of a function of random variable(s)? Well, simply speaking (that is,
without dragging in measure theory and abstract formulations),
the law of the unconscious
statistician says that we multiply $g(X_1,X_2)$ by the (joint)
density (or mass function) of $(X_1, X_2)$ and integrate (or sum)
the product. The law of iterated expectation tells us that

$$E[g(X_1,X_2)] = E\left[ E[Y \mid X_1, X_2]\right] = E[Y],\tag{1}$$
that is, this *function* of $X_1$ and $X_2$ that seemingly has
nothing to do with $Y$ if we look only at the expectation on the left
side of $(1)$ happens to have the *same* expected value as $Y$.

Remember that $E[Y]$ is just a constant, say $\mu_Y$, and 
thus $E[\mu_Y] = \mu_Y$ (and var$(\mu_Y) = 0$); that is how we statisticians incorporate into our math 
the unreasonable beliefs of our clients
who insist that they *expect* constants to have the same value at all times and not vary in any way!

Now, you want to show that
$$E[Y] = E\big[ E[E[Y \mid X_1, X_2]] \big]$$
which is straightforward: that expression *inside* the *bigger* square brackets on the right is a *constant* whose value is $\mu_Y = E[Y]$, and we have
just agreed (I hope) that $E[\mu_Y] = \mu_Y = E[Y]$.

---

It is possible that what the OP is asking about is a proof of
$$E[Y] = E\bigr[ E\big[E[Y \mid X_1, X_2]\mid X_1 \big] \bigr]\tag{2}$$
which lets us exercise the *iterated* part of the law of
iterated expectation some more.
We have already noted that $E[Y \mid X_1, X_2]$ is a random variable
$g(X_1, X_2)$ whose expected value just happens to equal $E[Y]$.
But what about the *conditional* expected value of $g(X_1,X_2)$ given
$X_1$? Well, $E[g(X_1,X_2)\mid X_1]$ is a *random variable* 
that happens to be a *function* of $X_1$, say $h(X_1)$, with the
useful property $E[h(X_1)]$ equals the *unconditional* expected
value $E[g(X_1,X_2)]$ of $g(X_1,X_2)$ and so we have that
$$
E\bigr[h(X_1)\bigr] = E\bigr[E\big[g(X_1,X_2)\mid X_1\big]\bigr]
= E\bigr[E\big[E[Y\mid X_1,X_2] \mid X_1\big]\bigr]$$
upon substituting $E\big[g(X_1,X_2)\mid X_1\big]$ for $h(X_1)$
and then substituting $E[Y\mid X_1,X_2]$ for $g(X_1,X_2)$.

So we have shown that the
right side of $(2)$ equals $E[h(X_1)]$ which equals $E[g(X_1,X_2)]$
which equals $E[Y]$, and we are done.

Comment: +1,I tried the same argument, but delete my answer since I am not sure for the solution..