# Law of iterated expectations for several variables

Tags: conditional-expectation

There are tons of questions related to the LIE, but all the ones I've seen do not help in my case, including [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730702/applying-iterated-expectation-when-conditioning-on-multiple-random-variables).

I know that by Law of Iterated Expectations (LIE), $E(x_{i}|A_{i})=0$ implies $E(x_{i}) = 0$ and $E(x_{i}A_{i})=0$.

In my case, I have $E(x_{i}|A_{i},B_{i},C_{i})=0$.

**Does that imply $E(x_{i}|A_{i},B_{i})=0$?**

I'm trying to work out the LIE formula but I'm not sure it's right. My developments so far:

$$ E(x_{i}|A_{i},B_{i},C_{i})=E(x_{i}A_{i}B_{i}C_{i})=E[A_{i}B_{i}E(x_{i}C_{i}|A_{i},B_{i})]=0 $$

Which means:

$$ E(x_{i}C_{i}|A_{i},B_{i})]=0= E(x_{i}C_{i})$$

Which means the latter two are independent, and therefore my result holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question and assumptions, then the answer is yes. This does not require any independence, but it does require that your conditional expectations are zero for *all* values of the auxiliary variables.

To show this mathematically, I will start with your first case (single auxiliary variable), then build to the more general case.

In the first instance, you have a variable of interest $x$, and a ["nuisance" variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_variable) $a$. The expectation of $x$ is defined as
$$\langle x\rangle=\int p[x] x dx$$
where $p[x]$ is the probability density function (PDF) of $x$.

Given the joint PDF $p[x,a]$ of $x$ and $a$, the conditional PDF of $x$ given $a$ is
$$p[x|a]=\frac{p[x,a]}{p[a]}$$
so the conditional expectation of $x$ given $a$ is
$$\langle x|a\rangle=\frac{1}{p[a]}\int p[x,a] x dx$$

Expressing the marginal PDF for $x$ as
$$p[x]=\int p[x,a]da$$
and substituting into the $\langle x\rangle$ equation, we then have 
$$\langle x\rangle=\int \langle x|a\rangle p[a] da$$
From this equation it follows that if $\langle x|a \rangle=0$ (for all $a$) then $\langle x\rangle=0$.

(Note that this derivation has *not* assumed independence, i.e. there is no need to have $p[x,a]=p[x]p[a]$.)

To generalize the result, it suffices to consider the case with two auxiliary variables $a$ and $b$. In this case, following along the path taken above, we have conditional probability
$$p[x|a,b]=\frac{p[x,a,b]}{p[a,b]}$$
conditional expectation
$$\langle x|a,b\rangle=\frac{1}{p[a,b]}\int p[x,a,b] x dx$$
and marginal (joint) probability
$$p[x,a]=\int p[x,a,b]db$$

Combining these we then have
$$\langle x|a\rangle=\frac{1}{p[a]}\int \langle x|a,b\rangle p[a,b] db$$
So if $\langle x|a,b \rangle=0$ (for all $a$ and $b$) then $\langle x|a\rangle=0$ for all $a$. (And from the first case, we then have $\langle x\rangle=0$.)

Comment: Thanks. That is not the notation I am used to, so it took me a while to understand. I will also write my answer based on my notation, more common in economics (my setting).

Comment: OK. Note that your subscripts do not appear to be necessary. That was confusing to me. Whatever the notation, the most important thing is that in the statement $E(x|A)=0$, the left hand side is a function of $A$, so the equality must be understood to apply for *all* values of $A$ that might occur. (So if $f[A]=E(x|A)$ then $p[A]>0$ must imply $f[A]=0$.)