# Implications of strict exogeneity for OLS in time series

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, assumptions, exogeneity

Zero Conditional Mean (ZCM), or Strict Exogeneity, is given by:
$E[u|X]=0$
Equivalently,
$E[u_t|X]=0, t=1,...,T$

Is it true that this implies:

- Zero Unconditional Mean: $E[u_t]=0, \forall t$
- Contemporaneous
  Exogeneity: $E[u_t|x_t]=0, \forall t $ (Where $x_t$ is a vector of
  explanatory variables)
- $E[x_su_t]=0, \forall t,s$

And are there any other things that ZCM imply that are particularly useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well consider the Law of Iterated expectation 
$$\mathbb  E[ \mathbb E[Y\lvert W]]= \mathbb E[Y]$$

and apply it with $Y=\mathbf u$ and $W = \mathbf X$, to get
$\mathbb  E[ \mathbb E[\mathbf u \lvert \mathbf X]]= \mathbb E[\mathbf u]$ and
$\mathbb  E[ \mathbb E[\mathbf u \lvert \mathbf X]] = \mathbb E[0] = 0$, hence $\mathbb E[\mathbf u]=0$.

Consider a generalized version of Law of Iterated Expectation mentioned in the post [A generalization of the Law of Iterated Expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations) which states that

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\lvert W_1,W_2] \lvert W_2] = \mathbb E[Y\lvert W_2]$$

and let $W_1 = \mathbf X\setminus \mathbf x_t$ (read $\mathbf X$ except the vector $\mathbf x_t$) and let $W_2=\mathbf x_t$ then

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[u_t\lvert \mathbf X]\lvert \mathbf x_t] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[u_t\lvert \mathbf X\setminus \mathbf x_t,\mathbf x_t]\lvert \mathbf x_t] = \mathbb E[u_t \lvert \mathbf x_t]$$
and as before it must be 0 because $\mathbb E[u_t\lvert \mathbf X]=0$.

Use the same argument to get $\mathbb E[u_t \lvert \mathbf x_s] = 0$ for all $s,t = 1,...,T$ and use this to conclude that

$$\mathbb E[u_t \mathbf x_s] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[u_t \mathbf x_s\lvert \mathbf x_s] ] = \mathbb E[ \mathbf x_s \mathbb E[u_t \lvert \mathbf x_s] ] = \mathbb E[ \mathbf x_s \cdot 0 ] = 0$$

So the answer must be yes they are all valid statements and further more $\mathbb E[u_t \lvert \mathbf x_s] = 0$ for all $s,t = 1,...,T$ as was used.

An intuitive statement of the statement $$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\lvert W_1,W_2] \lvert W_2] = \mathbb E[Y\lvert W_2]$$ is that the least information set always dominates so you also have
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\lvert W_2] \lvert W_1, W_2] = \mathbb E[Y\lvert W_2]$$
again this is mentioned in the post referred to above.

Comment: I think the variables in the first 3 lines are mixed up, but I get the point, thanks.

Comment: pls accept the answer if it was useful. I have edited the mix up.

Comment: Shouldn't the first equation be $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid W]]=\mathbb E[Y]$?

Comment: yes offcourse thx