# Is this formula for the Law of Iterated Expectations correct?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, conditional-expectation

I saw two versions of the law of iterated expectations, this one:
\begin{align}
E(E(Y\vert X)) = E(Y)
\end{align}
and this one:
\begin{align}
E(E(Y\vert X_1, X_2)\vert X_1) = E(Y \vert X_1)
\end{align}

I was wondering if this one is also correct or not:
\begin{align}
E(E(Y\vert Z) \vert X) = E(Y\vert X)
\end{align}

Here $X,X_1,X_2,Y,Z$ are random variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture is false. If $X=Y$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, $E(Y)=0$ then $E(Y|X)=Y$, $E(Y|Z)=0$, and $E(E(Y|Z)|X)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second version you state works but the third one does not is that "the smaller information set dominates", see this elaborate answer: [A generalization of the Law of Iterated Expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations/95972#95972)

Conditioning on $X_1,X_2$ means conditioning on more information than conditioning on $X_1$ alone, which implies that first conditioning on $X_1,X_2$ and then conditioning on $X_1$ is as good as the latter only.

In the third statement, we have no such relationship between $X$ and $Z$.