# Does $E(X \mid Y,Z)=0$ imply $E(X \mid Y)=0$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Does $E(X \mid Y,Z)=0$ imply $E(X \mid Y)=0$?

In other words, if we have $E(X \mid Y,Z)=0$ then can we also say $E(X \mid Y)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by the law of iterated expectations (with a [slight generalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations)):

$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y,Z\right)\mid Z\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[0\mid Z\right]=0$.