# Conditional Expectation with two random variables

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation

I know $E[E[x\mid y]] = E[x]$ by smoothing property of the expectations. Then, I came across the following equation:

[image]

In this equation we have:

$$E[E[x\mid A,Z]\mid Z] = E[x\mid Z]$$

I try to convince myself that the above formula is correct and tried this:

$$E[E[\underbrace{x}_{x\mid A}|\underbrace{y}_Z]\mid Z] = E[\underbrace{x}_{x\mid A}\mid Z] = E[x\mid A,Z]$$

What is wrong with the above equation? Furthermore, I do not understand how you make this transition:

$$E[E[x\mid A,Z]\mid Z] = E[x\mid A,Z]\Pr[A\mid Z]$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see your first transition is wrong because the right-hand side is a function of $A$ and $Z$ and the left-hand side is a function only of $Z$. That suggests the second equality is where the problem happens, and it is.

In $E[ E[x|A] |Z]$, the inner random variable is a function of $A$, and the outer expectation gives you the expected value of that function of $A$ conditional on $Z$, which is a function only of $Z$, with $A$ smoothed out by averaging.

In fact, the equation
$$E[E[x\mid A,Z] \mid Z] = E[x\mid Z]$$
is just another case of the smoothing rule (law of total expectation, tower rule). Wikipedia covers it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Your second transition is wrong, so that's why you don't understand how to make it. As a counterexample, suppose $A$, $X$, and $Z$ are all independent, and $P(A)<1$. Because of independence, $$E[E[x|A,Z]|Z]=E[x|A, Z]=E[x],$$ but $$E[x|A, Z]\Pr[A|Z]= E[x]P(A),$$ which is smaller than $E[x].$

The equation in the image (which wasn't there when I first answered the question) makes it clearer what the issue is. They have
$$E[E[x|A,Z]|Z]=\sum_{A_i} E[x|A, Z]P[A_i|Z]$$
What they mean by this is that $A_i$ are the possible value of $A$. In the original source they say

> The summation is over all events Ai in the set A of M mutually
>   exclusive and exhaustive association events.

Without $Z$ it would look like
$$E[E[x|A]]=\sum_{A_i} E[x|A]P[A_i]$$
which is just the law of total expectation applied to the *mutually
exclusive and exhaustive events* $A_i$

They have the same thing, only with everything conditioned on $Z$.

Comment: In fact the second transition is not my derivation, it is directly taken from the paper. Your argument seems logical to me but the authors stated it like this:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5338565, Equation (1), page 84.

Comment: What they have is $\sum_{A_i} E[X|A,Z_i]\Pr(A_i|Z)$ -- as you now have in the question but didn't before.  That is correct

Comment: Here is a detailed discussion on this topic:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-iterated-expectations
If anyone somehow came across this question, I suggest you to check it.